# Implementing Dijkstra's algorithm with vector of pointers

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, dijkstra

I'm working on a program involving Dijkstra's algorithm.

After searching long and far, I have only found help pertaining to Dijkstra's algorithm using Queues or Heaps, however, I am not using these. I have been tasked to used a vector of pointers to Vertex objects (a custom class I have defined).

I have attempted to convert the Queue pseudo code (from my textbook) to the best of my ability below:

```
void Dijkstra(vector<Vertex*> & V, int startNum)
{
    vector<Vertex*> sortedVertices = V;

    sortedVertices[startNum]->setDV(0);

    insertionSort(sortedVertices);

    while(sortedVertices.size() != 0)
    {
        sortedVertices[sortedVertices.size() - 1]->setKnown(true);
        sortedVertices.pop_back();
        insertionSort(sortedVertices);
        Vertex * v = V[1]; // Will always bring the first element off the list
        v->setKnown(true);

        for(int m = 0; m < sortedVertices->getAdjacentVertices().size(); m++)
        {
            int dist = getAdjacentVertices()[m].getWeight();
            if((sortedVertices[1].getDV() + dist) < sortedVertices[m+1]->getAdjacentVertices()[m].getDV())
            {
                //WE WILL DECREASE THE VALUE HERE by finding the distance between two vertices
                cout << "It works so far" << endl;
                // BOOK has this, somehow need to change it: w.path = v
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

However, when I attempt to compile, I keep receiving the following errors:

```
Main.cpp: In function 'void Dijkstra(std::vector<Vertex*>&, int)':
Main.cpp:154:42: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::vector<Vertex*>'
Main.cpp:156:44: error: 'getAdjacentVertices' was not declared in this scope
Main.cpp:157:35: error: request for member 'getDV' in 'sortedVertices.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<Vertex*, std::allocator<Vertex*> >(1ul)', which is of pointer type '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<Vertex*> >::value_type {aka Vertex*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
Main.cpp:157:99: error: '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<Edge> >::value_type' has no member named 'getDV'
```

I am trying to reduce the amount of Code in this post, but if need to be, my entire code is below:

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Vertex.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
void shortestPath(vector<Vertex> & v);

template <typename Comparable>
void insertionSort(vector<Comparable> & a);

template <typename Comparable>
void insertionSort( vector<Comparable> & a, int left, int right );


///overload the less than operator in order to use the stl sort for vector
///print out the path for each vertex

int main()
{

    /////READ ALL THE STUFF INTO THE GRAPH////
    ifstream file;
    file.open("graph.txt");
    cout << "Opening file..." << endl;
    if(!file)
    {
        cout << "System failed to open file.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File successfully opened" << endl;
    }

    int numVertices;
    int numEdges;
    int num;
    int adjacentVertex;
    int weight;

    file >> numVertices;
    cout << "The number of vertices that are being read into the graph from the file: " << numVertices;
    cout << endl;
    vector<Vertex*> vertices;
    //vector<Vertex> vertices(numVertices + 1);

    Vertex * newVertex;

    vertices.push_back(NULL);

    cout << "SIZE: " << vertices.size() << endl;
    cout << "NUM VERTICES: " << numVertices << endl;
    for(int i=1;i < numVertices + 1; i++)
    {   
        file >> numEdges;
        cout << "At vertex " << i << " the number of edges is " << numEdges << endl;
        newVertex = new Vertex();

        //Using the i counter variable in the outer for loop to identify
        //the what vertex what are currently looking at in order to read in the correct adjacent vertex and weight
        cout << "LENGTH OF VERTICES[i]: " << vertices.size() << endl;
        newVertex->setVertexNum(i);
        //newVertex.setVertexNum(i);

        for(int j=1;j<=numEdges;j++)
        {
            file >> adjacentVertex;
            cout << "The adjacent vertex is: " << adjacentVertex << endl;


            file >> weight;
            cout << "The weight is: " <<  weight << endl;
            cout << endl;

            newVertex->setAdjacentVertex(adjacentVertex, weight);
        }
        //cout << "LENGTH OF VERTICES[i]: " << vertices.size() << endl;
        vertices.push_back(newVertex);
    }
    file.close();
    vector<Vertex*> sortedVertices = vertices;
    insertionSort(sortedVertices);


    cout << "SIZE: " << vertices.size() << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<vertices.size();i++)
    {
        cout << "V" << i << ":  ";
        cout << endl;
        if(vertices[i] != NULL)
        {
            cout << "DV Value: " << vertices[i]->getDV();
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Known Value: " << vertices[i]->getKnown();
            cout << endl;
        }
    }


    cout << "Sorted: " << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<sortedVertices.size();i++)
    {
        cout << "V" << i << ":  ";
        cout << endl;
        if(vertices[i] != NULL)
        {
            cout << "DV Value: " << sortedVertices[i]->getDV();
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Known Value: " << sortedVertices[i]->getKnown();
            cout << endl;
        }
    }    





    //CALL THE SHORTEST PATH FUNCTION ON THE GRAPH/////



}

/*
const bool myFunction(const Vertex & x, const Vertex & y)
{
    return (x.getDV() >= y.getDV());
}
*/

bool operator < (const Vertex & v1, const Vertex & v2)
{
    return v1.getDV() > v2.getDV();
}

void Dijkstra(vector<Vertex*> & V, int startNum)
{
    vector<Vertex*> sortedVertices = V;

    sortedVertices[startNum]->setDV(0);

    insertionSort(sortedVertices);

    while(sortedVertices.size() != 0)
    {
        sortedVertices[sortedVertices.size() - 1]->setKnown(true);
        sortedVertices.pop_back();
        insertionSort(sortedVertices);
        Vertex * v = V[1]; // Will always bring the first element off the list
        v->setKnown(true);

        for(int m = 0; m < sortedVertices->getAdjacentVertices().size(); m++)
        {
            int dist = getAdjacentVertices()[m].getWeight();
            if((sortedVertices[1].getDV() + dist) < sortedVertices[m+1]->getAdjacentVertices()[m].getDV())
            {
                //WE WILL DECREASE THE VALUE HERE by finding the distance between two vertices
                cout << "It works so far" << endl;
                // BOOK has this, somehow need to change it: w.path = v
            }
        }
    } 
}

////////INSERTION SORT////////////
template <typename Comparable>
void insertionSort( vector<Comparable> & a )
{
    for( int p = 1; p < a.size( ); ++p )
    {
        Comparable tmp = std::move( a[ p ] );

        int j;
        for( j = p; j > 0 && tmp < a[ j - 1 ]; --j )
            a[ j ] = std::move( a[ j - 1 ] );
        a[ j ] = std::move( tmp );
    }
}

template <typename Comparable>
void insertionSort( vector<Comparable> & a, int left, int right )
{
    for( int p = left + 1; p <= right; ++p )
    {
        Comparable tmp = std::move( a[ p ] );
        int j;

        for( j = p; j > left && tmp < a[ j - 1 ]; --j )
            a[ j ] = std::move( a[ j - 1 ] );
        a[ j ] = std::move( tmp );
    }
}
```

Vertex.h:

```
#include "Edge.h"
#include <vector>
#include <climits>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class Vertex
{
    private:
        int vertexNum; //number of the vertex for identification purposes
        int degree;
        bool known;
        vector<Edge> adjacentVertices; //vector of vertices that are adjacent to the vertex we are currently looking at
        int dv; //distance 
        int pv; //previous vertex
        Vertex *vertex;
    public:
        Vertex()
        {
            dv = INT_MAX;
            known = false;
        }

        void setKnown(bool Known)
        {
            known = Known;
        }

        bool getKnown()
        {
            return known;
        }

        void setVertexNum(int VertexNum)
        {
            vertexNum = VertexNum;
        }

        void setDegree(int Degree)
        {
            degree = Degree;
        }

        vector<Edge> & getAdjacentVertices()
        {
            return adjacentVertices;
        }

        int getVertexNum()
        {
            return vertexNum;
        }

        int getDegree()
        {
            return degree;
        }

        int getDV() const 
        {
            return dv;
        }

        int setDV(int Dv)
        {
            dv = Dv;
        }

        void setAdjacentVertex(int AdjacentVertex, int Weight)
        {
            Edge newEdge;
            newEdge.setWeight(Weight);
            newEdge.setAdjVertex(AdjacentVertex);
            adjacentVertices.push_back(newEdge);
        }

        friend ostream & operator <<(ostream & outstream, Vertex *vertex)
        {
            outstream << vertex->getVertexNum() << endl;
            outstream << vertex->getDegree() << endl;
            outstream << vertex->getKnown() << endl;
            vector<Edge> E = vertex->getAdjacentVertices();
            for(int x=0;x<E.size();x++)
            {
                outstream << E[x].getAdjVertex() << endl;
                outstream << E[x].getWeight() << endl;
            }
            return outstream;
        }

        friend bool operator < (const Vertex & v1, const Vertex & v2);

};
```

Edge.h:

```
#include <cstdlib>
class Edge
{
    private:
        int adjVertex; //represents the vertex that the edge leads to
        int weight;
    public:
        Edge()
        {
            adjVertex = 0;
            weight = 0;
        }
        void setWeight(int Weight)
        {
            weight = Weight;
        }

        void setAdjVertex(int adjacent)
        {
            adjVertex = adjacent;
        }

        int getAdjVertex()
        {
            return adjVertex;
        }

        int getWeight()
        {
            return weight;
        }
};
```

Comment: Come on, the error message is telling you what the error is, and where it is... What more do you want?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I understand that, but why am I getting non-pointer type errors when it's clearly a vector of pointers?

Comment: A vector of pointers is not a pointer!!!

Comment: as an aside, why is `adjacentVertices` private variable? You return a reference to it in `getAdjacentVertices()` and do nothing else, so you aren't protecting it from anything. Then again, you never use `getAdjacentVertices()` as an lvalue, so I guess you don't need to return a reference anyways.

Answer (score 2):

From `g++` to English:

```
Main.cpp: In function 'void Dijkstra(std::vector<Vertex*>&, int)':
Main.cpp:154:42: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::vector<Vertex*>'
Main.cpp:156:44: error: 'getAdjacentVertices' was not declared in this scope
Main.cpp:157:35: error: request for member 'getDV' in 'sortedVertices.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<Vertex*, std::allocator<Vertex*> >(1ul)', which is of pointer type '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<Vertex*> >::value_type {aka Vertex*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
Main.cpp:157:99: error: '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<Edge> >::value_type' has no member named 'getDV'
```

Explanation:

`for(int m = 0; m < sortedVertices->getAdjacentVertices().size(); m++)` <- this is 154. `sortedVertices` is not a pointer. It is a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of some pointers.

`int dist = getAdjacentVertices()[m].getWeight();` <- 156. What is `getAdjacentVertices`?

`sortedVertices[1].getDV()` <- 157 `sortedVertices[1]` **is** a pointer. Look at [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)

`sortedVertices[m+1]->getAdjacentVertices()` is a `vector` of `Edge`. `Edge` does not have a `getDV()` method defined.

Is this really your code?

As an author you should not have trouble understanding the error messages. Those are simple mistakes, that took 5 minutes for a stranger to understand. You need to put more effort in understanding what you write, and what compiler tells you. Or get some sleep to get some focus.

I would also suggest to spend some time working out what `std::vector` really is and how to understand `std::vector<Vertex*> vector_of_vertices;` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<Vertex*> sortedVertices = V;

sortedVertices[startNum]->setDV(0)
```

Here you create variable of type `vector<Vertex*>` on the stack. This is not a pointer. This is a container containing pointers of type `Vertex*` and that's completely different. You use `->` operator which is only used on pointers.